# Prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} g(x-q_n)$ is absolutely convergent almost everywhere; $g(x)=x^{-1/3}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q} = \{q_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $g(x) = \begin{cases} x^{-\frac{1}{3}}& x \neq 0\\ 0& x=0 \end{cases}$.

I can't figure out how to prove the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} g(x-q_n)$ converges almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$. This is not homework, I'm studying for an upcoming exam. I quite honestly have no idea how to proceed, I tried fitting $\frac{1}{n^2}|g(x-q_n)|$ into some other sequence $x_n$ greater than it and such that $\sum_n x_n$ converges, but failed miserably.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you are enumerating over all rational number? For instance if you choose $   q_{n^2} = -n^7$ then for all $x$  $\frac{1}{n^2}g(x-q_n)\not \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your comment. Yes, according to the problem set I'm following (it's not from any specific book that I know of), $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I also don't understand why $\frac{1}{n^2}g(x-q_n)  \not\to 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$? I know that if $\frac{1}{n^2}g(x-q_n)$ does converge, then every subsequence also converges to the same limit. So if we consider the subsequence $\frac{1}{n_m^2}g(x-q_{n_m})$ with $n_m = m^2$, then isn't $\frac{1}{n_m^2}g(x-q_{n_m}) \to 0$ and thus $\frac{1}{n^2}g(x-q_n) \to 0$?

Comment: To clarify: $x-q_{n_m} = 0$ at most for one $m \in \mathbb{N}$, and thus $\lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{1}{n_m^2}g(x-q_{n_m}) =  \lim_{m \to \infty} \frac{\left(x+m^7\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{m^4} = \lim_{m\to\infty} \frac{\left(m^7\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \left(1 + \frac{x}{m^7}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{m^4} = \lim_{m\to\infty} m^{-\frac{7}{3}-4} \cdot 1 = 0$ because $\left(1 + \frac{x}{m^7}\right)^{-1/3} \to 1$.